# Deletion of script file doesn't affect the program

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC Application, I have a script file to perform inline operations in datatable such as insert, delete, update etc. I found that the script is not working as expected. So i tried editing the script file. It doesn't change the previous result. After that i deleted the script file from the solution. Then rebuild and run the application. Took the page source of the page from the browser and clicked the link to the script. Then the script file opened. I was surprised and checked the project solution again. But the script file was not there. How is it possible ?

Comment: check the console and see if there is warning/error for script not found

Comment: No. But is there any cache to store the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clear your browser cache

And then try again

Hope that will work.